# Put array inside attribute of blade template

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have some problem to set image as array inside attribute in blade template. Normally we use this inside HTML code

```
<div data-zs-src='["fronend/image/1.jpg", "fronend/image/2.jpg", "fronend/image/3.jpg"]' data-zs-overlay="dots">
    <!--some code-->
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it in Blade template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send your array to the blade view as a variable `$my_array` for example then attach it to the attribute.

In action :

```
$my_array = "[".implode(',', ["fronend/image/1.jpg", "fronend/image/2.jpg", "fronend/image/3.jpg"])."]";
```

In view :

```
<div data-zs-src='{{ $my_array }}' data-zs-overlay="dots">
```

If you've static array and you call your view directly you could define the variable inside the blade, like :

```
@php $my_array = "[".implode(',', ["fronend/image/1.jpg", "fronend/image/2.jpg", "fronend/image/3.jpg"])."]" @endphp

<div data-zs-src='{{ $my_array }}' data-zs-overlay="dots">
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can `escape` data within your blade templates using an `@` symbol at the beginning of a blade tag.

So in your case:

```
<div data-zs-src='@{{ ["fronend/image/1.jpg", "fronend/image/2.jpg", "fronend/image/3.jpg"] }}' data-zs-overlay="dots">
    <!--some code-->
</div>
```

All data within this tag will not be processed by blade.